# Haskell read multiple files

Tags: haskell, readfile

I'm trying to read multiples files at once using the following code. 
The code compiles, however when executed I get the following exception:

*** Exception: ..: openFile: permission denied (Permission denied).

I have all the permissions as system administrator. Also, I was able to do the same in C# with no problem, meaning/suspecting that it's an issue with the code itself.

Thanks for help.

```
main :: IO()
main = do 
   putStrLn " Enter file path:"
   content <- getLine >>= getDirectoryContents
   x <- mapM readFile content
   print x
```

Comment: the function getDirectoryContents  returns also the directories [".",".."], so you need to filter them  `filter (flip notElem [".", ".."])`

Comment: Thanks ! it was indeed a problem of filtering the list which I didn't figure out in first place "visually" taking into consideration the important number of txt files to be processed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure all of the files are actually files? It looks like you're trying to open a file called `..`.

Filter the results to only include actual files first.

Comment: That's the problem. `..` is not a file but a directory (the up-link to the parent directory). Directories can't be opened with `readFile`. FWIW, I get a clearer error message: `*** Exception: .: openFile: inappropriate type (is a directory)`. I suspect the OP is on Windows, which isn't so explainative about such issues.

Comment: Thanks ! I'm using windows, the directory contains so many txt files that's why I didn't catch the problem (..) in the returned list.  With list filtered it's now working.